# `nc` (netcat) hangs indefinitely when reading from initially empty named pipe

Tags: command-line, 20.04, pipe, netcat

I start an `nc` server like this:

```
nc -lk -p 12345 -s localhost < <named_pipe>
```

and an `nc` client with:

```
nc localhost 12345
```

When I run the command and the pipe is empty, `nc` hangs, which is what I expect. However, even when I start writing to the pipe, e.g. with:

```
watch -n 3 -t fortune > p
```

`nc` still remains waiting.

When I run `systrace` on the server, I see this:

```
strace: Process <id> attached
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted read ...>
```

indicating that the process is waiting on a read operation.

If I systrace the producer I can see constant writes to the named pipe. It's not clear why the server is waiting when data is available on the pipe.

However, if I kill the client and launch it again, thus reinitiating the connection, everything works fine.

System information:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
BSD nc
```

Comment: I could not reproduce "When I run the command and the pipe is empty, nc hangs". On my machine, `nc localhost 12345` immediately returns and prints nothing